# Replacing multiple patterns in a block of data

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm

I need to find the most efficient way of matching multiple regular expressions on a single block of text. To give an example of what I need, consider a block of text:

"Hello World what a beautiful day"

I want to replace Hello with "Bye" and "World" with Universe. I can always do this in a loop ofcourse, using something like String.replace functions availiable in various languages.

However, I could have a huge block of text with multiple string patterns, that I need to match and replace.

I was wondering if I can use Regular Expressions to do this efficiently or do I have to use a Parser like LALR.

I need to do this in JavaScript, so if anyone knows tools that can get it done, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass a function to replace:

```
var hello = "Hello World what a beautiful day";
hello.replace(/Hello|World/g, function ($0, $1, $2) // $3, $4... $n for captures
{
    if ($0 == "Hello")
        return "Bye";
    else if ($0 == "World")
        return "Universe";
});

// Output: "Bye Universe what a beautiful day";
```

Comment: Just a note, Andy E: You need a `)` before your `;` on the last line :)

Comment: @smotchkkiss: Yeah, I noticed that as I was typing the comment at the bottom and completely forgot about it by the time I finished! Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. However, are regex matches limited to $1..$9 or can we also have $10, $11 etc....

Comment: @VikrantY: I probably confused you by using the same naming convention for the arguments as of those properties you find on the `RegExp` object.  There are no limits (as far as I am aware) for the number of arguments passed to the replace function callback.  Also, if your regexp consists of no substring captures then the only argument you're working with is `$0`.

Answer (score 16):

Edit

6 years after my original answer (below) I would solve this problem differently

```js
function mreplace (replacements, str) {
  let result = str;
  for (let [x, y] of replacements)
    result = result.replace(x, y);
  return result;
}

let input = 'Hello World what a beautiful day';

let output = mreplace ([
  [/Hello/, 'Bye'],
  [/World/, 'Universe']
], input);

console.log(output);
// "Bye Universe what a beautiful day"
```

This has as tremendous advantage over the previous answer which required you to write each match twice. It also gives you individual control over each match. For example:

```js
function mreplace (replacements, str) {
  let result = str;
  for (let [x, y] of replacements)
    result = result.replace(x, y);
  return result;
}

let input = 'Hello World what a beautiful day';

let output = mreplace ([
  //replace static strings
  ['day', 'night'],
  // use regexp and flags where you want them: replace all vowels with nothing
  [/[aeiou]/g, ''],
  // use captures and callbacks! replace first capital letter with lowercase 
  [/([A-Z])/, $0 => $0.toLowerCase()]

], input);

console.log(output);
// "hll Wrld wht  btfl nght"
```

---

Original answer

[Andy E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-e)'s answer can be modified to make adding replacement definitions easier.

```
var text = "Hello World what a beautiful day";
text.replace(/(Hello|World)/g, function ($0){
  var index = {
    'Hello': 'Bye',
    'World': 'Universe'
  };
  return index[$0] != undefined ? index[$0] : $0;
});

// "Bye Universe what a beautiful day";
```

Comment: Thanks Andy/smotchkiss you have both completely sorted my problem and avoided me having to write my own algorith, for multiple replacement.

Comment: Probably you shouldn't be re-creating the lookup object for each call to the replacement function, right, but instead have it outside?

Answer (score 1):

An improved answer:

```
var index = {
    'Hello': 'Bye',
    'World': 'Universe'
};

var pattern = '';
for (var i in index) {
    if (pattern != '') pattern += '|';
    pattern += i;
}

var text = "Hello World what a beautiful day";
text.replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'g'), function($0) {
    return index[$0] != undefined ? index[$0] : $0;
});
```

Comment: It's an old question with old answers. I think you offer a good improvement, but you can extend even more power to the user by not forcing their input through the `RegExp` constructor and auto-appending `g` flag.

Answer (score 1):

A common task involving replacing a number of patterns is making a user's or other string "safe" for rendering on Web pages, which means preventing HTML tags from being active. This can be done in JavaScript using HTML entities and the forEach function, allowing a set of exceptions (that is, a set of HTML tags that will be allowed to render).

This is a common task, and here is a fairly brief way to accomplish it:

```
// Make a string safe for rendering or storing on a Web page
function SafeHTML(str)
    {
    // Make all HTML tags safe
    let s=str.replace(/</gi,'&lt;');

    // Allow certain safe tags to be rendered
    ['br','strong'].forEach(item=>
        {
        let p=new RegExp('&lt;(/?)'+item+'>','gi');
        s=s.replace(p,'<$1'+item+'>');
        });
    return s;
    } // SafeHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to replace multiple *generic* patterns with corresponding replacements - either [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) or [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), it's quite tricky because of special characters, capturing groups and backreference matching.

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/union-replacer for this exact purpose. It is basically a `string.replace(regexp, string|function)` counterpart, which allows multiple replaces to happen in one pass while preserving full power of `string.replace(...)`.

Disclosure: I am the author and the library was developed because we had to support user-configured replaces.