# Is there a better way to condense this?

Tags: jquery

I'm getting information from an API which is unformatted and trying to format it using replace.

At the moment I have code like:

```
jobContainer.find('#job-description').html(theDescription.replace(/Â£/gi, '&pound;').replace(/\n\n/g,'<br><br>').replace(/\*/g, '<br><br>&#8226;&nbsp;&nbsp;'))
```

replacing strange pound signs with proper pound signs, \n\n with line breaks, and * with line breakk>bullet point>spaces

At the moment I'm using 3 separate replace methods, can I condense this down better?

Comment: Sure, write it in a function and never look at it again.

Comment: what is your goal? easier to read, quicker to execute, maybe something else?

Comment: quickest to execute important, but using 3 replace's seems unnecessary? can it be put into 1?

Comment: You can use a replacement map and do a single replace with function callback, but that would probably not make it any faster.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2502158/276263