# C# Replace all instances in a string with any string from an IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, regex

I have a `string Snippet` and an `IEnumerable<string> Highlights`. I would like to search `Snippet` for all instances of any string from `Highlights`, then wrap the words with a span. I already set up a `Regex.Replace` when there was only a single `string Highlight`, but now that there are many options, I am not sure of how to change the code.

**Example:**

```
Snippet = "Jack and Jill went up the hill to fetch some water"
Highlights = "Jack", "hill", "to"
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Snippet = "<span>Jack</span> and Jill went up the <span>hill</span> <span>to</span> fetch some water"
```

**Old Code for Single String:**

```
Regex.Replace(Snippet, Highlight, ReplaceHighlightWords, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase

private string ReplaceHighlightWords(Match m)
{
    return "<span class=\"text-highlight\">" + m.Value + "</span>";
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output if one of your highlights is a part of another?  For example, `Highlights = "hill", "ill"`

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501435/replacing-multiple-patterns-in-a-block-of-data) SO question?

Comment: @BrianRogers It should still highlight it, so I don't need to worry about searching only for full words

Comment: @OstrichGlue: I wonder how many times you need to call the `Regex.Replace`. With my approach, you only have to call it once, and only replace the non-overlapping matches on the go. If you also use the [`Calculate` method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35481514/3832970) to create the regex from the *Highlights*, it will be the fastest solution.

Comment: If these strings are the same every time, you don't need to calculate a regex. If they are the same, just put them into a list and paste them into [`here`](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht01.jpg). Out pops a ternary tree regex that is faster than any other method. You compile on program startup, and you're done. Example of 175.000 word dictionary [`here`](http://www.regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_Ternary_Tool%20(Dictionary)/___txt/_ASCII_175,000_word_Mix_A-Z_Multi_Lined.txt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an alternation:

```
var rx = string.Forma(@"\b(?:{0})\b", string.Join("|", Highlights));
var res = Regex.Replace(Snippet, rx,
     "<span class=\"text-highlight\">$&</span>", 
     RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The word boundaries `\b` will handle the cases when you  have both `to` and `together` among `Highlights`. ***NOTE* that you may omit `\b` altogether to match substrings inside words.**

The `$&` in the replacement pattern inserts the whole match value in the result.

If `Highlights` may contain special chars like `(` or `[`, escape them with `Regex.Escape` first, and - if you want to match whole words only in this scenario -  instead of `\b` use `@"(?<!\w)(?:{0})(?!\w)"`. Here is the more advanced snippet:

```
var Snippet = "Jack and Jill went up the (hill) to fetch some water";
var Highlights = new string[] { "Jack", "(hill)", "to" };
var rx = string.Format(@"(?<!\w)(?:{0})(?!\w)",
    string.Join("|", Highlights.Select(p => Regex.Escape(p))));
var res = Regex.Replace(Snippet, rx,
        "<span class=\"text-highlight\">$&</span>", 
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(res);
// => <span class="text-highlight">Jack</span> and Jill went up the
// <span class="text-highlight">(hill)</span> <span class="text-highlight">to</span> 
//fetch some water
```

See [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/VF86l5)

There is a thread on how to build an optimized alternative list for a regex based replacement like this at [*Generating the Shortest Regex Dynamically from a source List of Strings*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429224/generating-the-shortest-regex-dynamically-from-a-source-list-of-strings), might be worth checking, too.

Comment: Thanks for the response! You were correct, there were issues popping up with my approach. I edited my code to use your solution

Answer (score 3):

Nothing special to do here.  Just wrap what you already had in a loop.

```
var Highlights = new[] { "Jack", "hill", "to" };
foreach(var Highlight in Highlights) {
    Snippet = Regex.Replace(Snippet, Highlight, ReplaceHighlightWords, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}

private string ReplaceHighlightWords(Match m)
{
    return "<span class=\"text-highlight\">" + m.Value + "</span>";
}
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DbPf9L)

Comment: @wiktorstribizew Good point.  I was assuming this was something that he wanted, because in his example his code wouldn't work with the word "Jackie" in his string, either.

Comment: The problem as I see it with this approach is that once you replaced one word in a string, you modify the string that you process again *in full*. In my approach, the already modified part is not touched.

Comment: I don't think this is true, I made a [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DbPf9L) just to make sure and it shows the behavior that I'm expecting from his question.  I upvoted your question, though, because I think your answer is both faster, and more flexible.

Comment: Try with `var Highlights = new[] { "Jack", "hill", "together", "to" };` and you will see what I mean. Maybe `<span class="text-highlight"><span class="text-highlight">to</span>gether</span>` is OK for OP.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good question.  I'm not sure.  This comment stream is at least making him aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can **OR** your words like `string.Join("|", Highlights)`

```
var Snippet = "Jack and Jill went up the hill to fetch some water";
string[] Highlights = { "Jack", "hill", "to" };

var result = Regex.Replace(Snippet, 
                           string.Join("|", Highlights), 
                           m => "<span>" + m.Value + "</span>");
```